# Issue accessing a global variable variable

Tags: php

I'm am having trouble accessing a global variable variable (being an associative array) from within a function:

```
$arr1 = array(
    1 => "Alex1",
    2 => "Blah",
    3 => "Charlie"
);

$arr2 = array(
    1 => "D",
    2 => "E",
    3 => "F"
);

function GetVal()
{
  $x = 1;  // But could be any value
  $dd = $GLOBALS[${'arr'.$x}];

$ouput = $dd[1];    // should be "Alex1"
}
```

Gives Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$GLOBALS[${'arr'.$x}]` translates to `$GLOBALS[$arr1]` and `$arr1` doesn't exist in function scope, plus it's an array.  You need to get a string of `arr1` to use as the index:

```
$dd = $GLOBALS['arr'.$x]; // or use "arr$x"
```

That translates to `$GLOBALS['arr1']`.